# How to put adsorbate on the surface by ASE

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment

I would like to make formate-adsorbed surface on Cu(111). I have prepared the Cu(111) by ASE:

```
import numpy as np
from ase.build import surface
from ase.io import write, read
from ase.build import molecule
from ase.build import add_adsorbate

# Create the copper surface
slab = surface('Cu', (1, 1, 1), 4)
slab = slab.repeat((4, 4, 1))
slab.center(vacuum=10, axis=2)
```

How can I put 10 formated ions on the surface (in **bidentate** form) randomly? I don't know how to specify the ASE code to determine the ion as bidentate form, as well as the position of the adsorbates.

Answer (score 5):

ASE doesn't support adding multiple adsorbates. If you use the `ase.build.add_adsorbate` function multiple times, it will unfortunately add adsorbates to the same pre-defined position. This is a typical situation where you may consider using [ACAT](https://asm-dtu.gitlab.io/acat/). For your example, this can be simply achieved by the following code:

```
from ase.build import surface
from ase.visualize import view
from acat.build.adlayer import max_dist_coverage_pattern as mdcp
from acat.settings import site_heights

# Create the copper surface
slab = surface('Cu', (1, 1, 1), 4)
slab = slab.repeat((4, 4, 1))
slab.center(vacuum=10, axis=2)
# Add more heights to the CHOO*
heights = {k: v+0.5 for k, v in site_heights.items()}
# Generate a random surface coverage pattern with 10 CHOO*
atoms = mdcp(slab, adsorbate_species='CHOO', coverage=10/64,
             surface='fcc111', heights=heights)
view(atoms)
```

[image]

Now if you want to rotate the bidentate adsorbates, you can use ASE-GUI to do that, or if you want completely random generation, including the rotation of multidentate adsorbate species, you can use [`acat.build.RandomPatternGenerator`](https://asm-dtu.gitlab.io/acat/build.html#the-randompatterngenerator-class). It also allows you to specify which sites are not allowed to adsorb, and the minimum distance between two adsorbates. Below is an example:

```
from ase.io import read
from ase.build import surface
from ase.visualize import view
from acat.build.adlayer import RandomPatternGenerator as RPG
from acat.settings import site_heights

# Create the copper surface
slab = surface('Cu', (1, 1, 1), 4)
slab = slab.repeat((4, 4, 1))
slab.center(vacuum=10, axis=2)
# Add more heights to the CHOO*
heights = {k: v+0.5 for k, v in site_heights.items()}
gen = RPG(slab, adsorbate_species='CHOO',
          min_adsorbate_distance=1.5,
          surface='fcc111',
          heights=heights,
          species_forbidden_sites={'CHOO': ['ontop','bridge']},
          trajectory='Cu_111_10CHOO.traj')
gen.run(num_gen=1, action='add', num_act=10)
atoms = read('Cu_111_10CHOO.traj')
view(atoms)
```

[image]

**Disclaimer**: I am the developer of ACAT.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try using ACAT.

Comment: This is why there is an `cell` keyword which takes an (X, Y) offset for the next adsorbate when using ASE.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the "offset" parameter in ase.build.add_adsorbate to add multiple adsorbates. For example,add_adsorbate(slab,ad,adh,site,offset=(2,1)). As explained in the ASE doc site the adsorbate is added in the order of number of unit cells.

offset (default: None): Offsets the adsorbate by a number of unit
cells. Mostly useful when adding more than one adsorbate.

ase.build.add_adsorbate(slab, adsorbate, height, position=(0, 0), offset=None, mol_index=0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).